# Problems with authentication. Laravel

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I'm making authentication using Laravel framework. It's works, after passing a valid data to form auth will be perfomed. But there is a problem: after refreshing of page I'm losing authenticated user.

Here my UserController method:

```
public function LogIn(){
    $Data = Input::all();

    $Validator = $this::ValidateInputData($Data,'L');

    if($Validator->fails())
    {
        print "Ошибка, авторизация не произведена.";
        $Errors = $Validator->messages()->toArray();

        return View::make('signupView')->with('Errors',$Errors);
    }
    else{

     $User = User::ProceedLogining($Data,$this->GetStayedStatus(Input::get('Stay')));
     if ($User instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model)
     {
         Auth::login($User,$this->GetStayedStatus(Input::get('Stay')));

         return Redirect::to('/');
     }

      else{

          $Alert = 'Ошибка авторизации, проверьте правильность ввода данных.';
          return  View::make('signupView')->with('Alert',$Alert);
      }
    }
}
```

And my Model method:

```
public static function ProceedLogining($Data,$StayStatus){

        if (Auth::attempt([
            'login' => $Data['Login'],
            'password' => $Data['Password']
        ], $StayStatus))

         return Auth::user();
    else return 'Auth error';

}
```

Of course, first proposition will be checking "GetStayedStatus" function, but I tried pass 'true' values, It doesn't bring any positive results

Comment: This is a bit strange. Why do you have a method in your model to perform a  login? Is the "ValidateInputData" method declared as static? You are using the wrong syntax on that line.

Comment: I saw a tutorial, where author use such approach, is this wrong? 

'ValidateInputData' yes it is a static method

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved this. In my layout I had such code:

```
  @if(Sentry::check())
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Профиль {{Sentry::getUser()->login}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Мой кабинет (My profile) <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Обновления (News) <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span> </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Сообщения (Messages) <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span></a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href='logout'>Выход (log out)  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                @else
                    <div class="sign-up">
                        <a class="alert-link" href="{{URL::to("signup/")}}">Вход / Регестрация (Sign up) </a>
                    </div> <!-- End of sign-up -->
                @endif
```

In previous post I used built-in 'Auth' class, but in this you can see 'Sentry'- it doesn't matter, my problem still hasn't been solved.

So there are some actions what actually can help you.
1) Check your users table and ensure that you have 'id' field and it set as primary key.
2) Check your session.php, which located at App/config/ . Set 'driver' property to 'file'.
3) Unfortunately, these actions don't give any positive results. I will describe my instance.

Pay attention to this string: `<li><a href='logout'>Выход (log out)  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a></li>` , when I have this problem 'href' property was set to 'Sentry::LogOut()' or 'Auth::LogOut()', then I change it to route and problem gone.

Hope it will help!